# Youtube API - Get top comments from a video

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to get the top comments from a video? Maybe sorted by number of thumbs up?

This is my current url:

> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+yt_id+'/comments?alt=json-in-script&callback=?&max-results=50

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, i think there is no such option. You can´t (or i didn´t manage to get it working) order by rating, likes etc. of comment, because there is no gdata-tag like "rating" etc. for comments. YouTube doesn´t provide this so far. You can vote for it [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=660&q=label%3aAPI-YouTube&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary)

Answer (score 2):

Yes I found that sorting by relevance is a good way of doing this for example in JS:

```js
const comments = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=${YOUR_API_KEY}&textFormat=plainText&**order=relevance**&part=snippet&videoId=${YOUR_VID_ID}&maxResults=100`);
```